# Getting segmentation-fault when trying to assign character from getline

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, getline

So, I'm getting sentence using `getline(cin, str);` then `string text[str.length()];` and after this in for statement when i want to combine them ( `text[e] = text[e] + str[i];` ) I'm getting segmentation-fault. Full Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int i, e, space = 0;

    getline(cin, str);
    string text[str.length()];

    for(i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(str[i]==' ') {
            space++;
            e++;
        }
        else {
            text[e] = text[e] + str[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not standard (yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`e` is unitialized, and it will be holding a random value probably out of bounds of `text` causing the segmentation fault. This does not initialize all variables to zero:

```
int i, e, space = 0;
```

only `space` is initialized to zero. Change to:

```
int i = 0, e = 0, space = 0;
```

or:

```
int i = 0;
int e = 0;
int space = 0;
```

---

To my knowledge, c++ does not support variable length arrays.

Comment: LOL, i thought that int i,e,space = 0; will make all of them 0 :) Thanks

Comment: `int i, e, space;` `i=e=space=0;` would do that.